# Creating a Unique HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create an HTML form using Javascript that copies the contents of each field and Pastes's it into a singular textbox.

-------------- HTML Code Provided --------------------

```
    <form id="callflow" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">

    <div class="form_description">

    <h2>Callflow</h2>

    <p>Flowsheet to take notes and ensure you meet all QA elements on every call.</p>

    </div>                      

            <ul >

        <li id="li_1" >

        <label class="description" for="cust_name">Greet Customer </label> <br> 
        Thank you for calling ___________ My Name is David to Whom do I have the Pleasure of Speaking with today? <br><br>
        <label class="description" for="cust_name"> Customer Name</label>
        <div>
        <input id="cust_name" name="cust_name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        <br>
        </div>
        <label class="description" for="call_reason">Reason for the call. </label>
        <div>
        <textarea id="call_reason" name="call_reason" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div>


    </li>

<li id = "li_2" >
<label class="description" for="element_2">Provide Assurance Statement </label>
<p>____________ I want to personally apologize that your having to deal with this if this happened to me I would be fustrated as well.</p> <br>


</li>
<li id = "li_3" >
<label class="description" for="element_3">Provide Promoter Statement </label>
<p> This is not the experience we want our customers to have here at ______________. I would be more than happy to take care this for you. </p><br>
</li>

<li id="li_4" >
<label class="description" for="element_4">Ask Probing Questions:</label>
Why do you want to return [insert item]? <br>
Can I ask why your seeking to cancel your order? <br>
Was this item for an event? <br>
Could you describe the damage to me? 
<br>
<br>  
</li>
<li id = "li_5">
<label class="description" for="tailored_solution"> Propose Solution </label>
<p>D. Discount to keep. | R. Replacement Parts | U. Unit | M. Money Back</p> 
<br>
<div>
<textarea id="tailored_solution" name="tailored_solution" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div>
<br>
<br>
<label class="description" for="tailored_solution"> WRAP Call </label>

<p> It's going to take just a brief moment here for me to finish up processing this request for you. You wont hear anything but rest assured I am still here just holler if you need anything.  </p>
</li>
<li id="li_6" >

<label class="description" for="set_expectations">Recap & Set Expectations. </label>

<span>

<input id="set_expectations_discount" name="set_expectations_discount" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_discount">Discount Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_replacement" name="set_expectations_replacement" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_replacement">Replacement Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_refund" name="set_expectations_refund" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_refund">Refund Expectations</label>

<input id="set_expectations_return" name="set_expectations_return" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="set_expectations_return">Return Expectations</label>

</span> 

</li>
<li id="li_7" >

<label class="description" for="close">Check for Additional Needs Addressing  any Remaining Questions. </label>

<span>

<input id="close_1" name="close_1" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="close_1">Yes</label>

<input id="close_2" name="close_2" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />

<label class="choice" for="close_2">No</label>

</span> 
</li>
<li id = "li_8">
<label class="description" for="notes"> Generate Notes  </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="notes_gen" onclick="FillNotes(this.form)">
<em>Check this box to generate notes.</em>
<div>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
</div>


<li class="buttons">

<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="6865" />


<input id="clearForm" class="button_text" type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear" />

</li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

--------------- Javascript Code provided ------------------

```
    function FillNotes(f) {
  if(f.notes.checked == true) {
    f.notes.value = f.cust_name.value;
    f.notes.value = f.call_reason.value;
    f.notes.value = f.tailored_solution.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_discount.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_refund.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_replacement.value;
    f.notes.value = f.set_expectations_return.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close_1.value;
    f.notes.value = f.close_2.value;
  }
  }
}
```

Now I want it to Copy the contents of each checkbox & text area except the last textbox  where I want it to paste into and add a separator between each entry like | or /

Firstly What am I doing wrong 2nd'y my JS is subpar at best. Would someone be willing to help me?

PS the submit button has been replaced with reset as this is intended to be a replacement for "notetaking" at work so we can remove access to stickynote on agent computers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#copy").click(function() {

$('#callflow *').filter(':input').each(function() {
let elem = $("#notes");
let thisElem = $(this)[0];

if (thisElem.value && (thisElem.type === "text" || thisElem.type === "textarea")) {
  elem.val(elem.val() + "|" + thisElem.value);
} else if (thisElem.type === "checkbox" && thisElem.checked) {
  elem.val(elem.val() + "|" + thisElem.nextElementSibling.innerHTML);
}
  });

});
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/andykarwal/oepjbvz8/